# Java Подбор минимального количества чисел из заданого массива для поиска нужной суммы

Tags: java, массивы, циклы

Задача в Java.

Пользователь будет вводить число (`Scanner`).

- У вас есть монетки номиналом 1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 50.
- Провести вычисление минимального количества монеток, нужных для описания числа пользователя.
- Результат вывести на экран с сопутствующими сообщениями.

Например, приходит число 127 - минимум нужно 4 монетки: 2 номиналом 50, 1 номиналом 25 и 1 номиналом 2.

Comment: а в чём проблема? При таких номиналах можно использовать жадный алгоритм даже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int number = введенное число;
int[] coins = {50,25,10,5,2,1};
Map<Integer, Integer> result = new HashMap();
for (int coin : coins) {
    int count = number / coin;
    number -= count * coin;
    if (count > 0) {
       result.put(coin, count)
    };
}
```

Comment: А можете помочь,  без использование map і hashmap?

Comment: убираете map и заменяете его на что вам угодно, хоть на System.out.println